# CakePHP: Using Constant array for Form Field

Tags: cakephp, organization, cakephp-2.1

`Users` have many `Instruments`, but `Instruments` are static so I'd like to use them by referring to a defined constant array rather than retrieving them from the database. This array needs to be accessible by **Views** and **Controllers**.

I also feel that stuffing a bunch of random unrelated constants in `bootstrap` is mess.

What is the best way to do this - where should I put this array?

Comment: you know, thats what bootstrap is THERE for. If it bothers you that much, create a class in libs and import that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use some kind of enum I guess you are looking for that:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/

```
public static function instruments {}
```

But in your case Instruments shouldnt be static but a real table with data (Instrument belongsTo User - e.g. multiple rows with the same user_id). Enums only work the other way around (on belongsTo relations).

Or is there a specific reason it has to be static? The main problem with your question is how the data can be properly stored. What instruments belong to what users?

If you really want to store such an array list in a single column of the user (which I don't recommend in your case), you could use a bitmask:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/02/26/bitmasked-using-bitmasks-in-cakephp/

Comment: I seem to have misled you. A user has many instruments. I don't want to define the instruments in the database (for example, table instruments would contain guitar, piano, etc). Instead, I want to take the data that would define the instruments and just store it in an array. I'm wondering if using `$useTable = false` is a good idea, and just defining a static array in the `Instruments` model.

Comment: ok, sure, but that still does not explain where you store the relation data (user_id, instrument_id). you got some field in the user table? or is this data not stored in the DB at all?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Array Datasource. It lets you define static arrays of data and still use associations.